# How to set multiple fields in vue.js with google autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, autocomplete, google-places-api

I'm trying to use google autocomplete to fill in multiple fields with a single selection in a vue.js file. Where am I getting the address_components from? The vue-google-autocomplete comes from here: https://github.com/olefirenko/vue-google-autocomplete

I have so far tried to follow the same google address form found on here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete-addressform

In the console I get this error `TypeError: "e[s] is undefined"`

For the HTML component I have:

```
      <label >City</label>
      <vue-google-autocomplete ref="locality" id="locality" class="form-control" type="text" v-on:placechanged="getAddressData" placeholder="Enter city" country="us"></vue-google-autocomplete>
   </div>
   <div class="col" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <label >State</label>
      <vue-google-autocomplete ref="administrative_area_level_1" id="administrative_area_level_1" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="2" v-on:placechanged="getAddressData" placeholder="Enter State" country="us"></vue-google-autocomplete>
   </div>
   <div class="col" style="margin-bottom: 20px;">
      <label >Zip Code</label>
      <vue-google-autocomplete ref="postal_code" id="postal_code" class="form-control" type="text" maxlength="5" v-on:placechanged="getAddressData" placeholder="Enter zip code"></vue-google-autocomplete>
   </div>
```

So far I have once been able to get 3 fields to fill with `Object object` somehow but I can't seem to reproduce that since I have changed it.

```
return{
  componentForm: {
              street_number: '',
              route: '',
              locality: '',
              administrative_area_level_1: '',
              country: '',
              postal_code: ''
  }
}

getAddressData: function (addressData, placeResultData) {
   for(var i = 0; i < placeResultData.address_components.length; i++) {
       var addressType = placeResultData[i].types[0]
       if(this.componentForm[addressType]) {
           var val = placeResultData.address_components[i][this.componentForm[addressType]]
           document.getElementById(addressType).value = val
       }
   }
}
```

I would like to get multiple fields to fill with all the place components that I get returned but I'm not sure why my getAddressData isn't setting the value of the individual components.

Comment: So what is your question? Can you be more specific?

Comment: When I click on an address in the autocomplete popup window it only fills the current box with the entire address rather than filling all boxes with individual components. I can't figure out what's wrong with using googles address form example being used in vue.js

Comment: Can you provide other boxes?

Comment: I added 3 fields to the body

Comment: As far as I understand the placeResultData parameter is `autocomplete.Place()` so it should have address_components attached to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
getAddressData (event){
   console.log(event);
   if (event.address_components){
      if (event.address_components[2].long_name) {
         this.$el.querySelector('#locality').value = event.address_components[2].long_name; //Check from console
      }
      if (event.address_components[4].long_name) {
         this.$el.querySelector('#administrative_area_level_1').value = event.address_components[4].long_name; //Check from console
      }
   }
}
```

**Note**

Check in event which data you need, I m not sure about names. But I think this should work fine and populate your inputs.

Comment: So the good thing is it is showing all components when logging the event object. Im now getting this error `TypeError: "t.address_components is undefined"`

Comment: Are your inputs filled? I updated my answer. But be careful about `address_components[2]` because I m not sure which one is city or state or zip. You will find that in your `event`. Good Luck.

Comment: Worked! I had to include a second parameter because event doesn't hold the address_components. I changed `this.$el.querySelector('#administrative_area_level_1')` to `document.getElementById(someId).value` and it populated them all. Thank You!

Comment: You are welcome. I would be grateful if you mark answer as useful. :)